# String.contains() when reading from file

Tags: java, string

I am reading from a file line by line and then I want to check if that string contains another string so I use `String.contains` method but it returns always false.

I have tried to split the input line (and then using `String.contains` or `String.equals`) since the word to be checked is the first of the line.

The string I want to check is `<now>` and doing the splitting I have noticed that even when the line contains it I get false.

The strange fact is the string is printed out correctly but its length is bigger than the string `<now>`(even if I used replace to be sure there were no spaces) and I guess that is my problem. I am thinking it depends on the encoding of file but if so, is there any solution?

The file is the output of another Program (Praat) so I can not save it in another way.

```
line = inFile2.nextLine();
String[] w = line.split("[\t\\s]");
String checking = w[0];
checking.replace(" ","");
checking.replace("/t","");
String st ="<now>";
System.out.println(!checking.equals(st)); //returns always true
System.out.println(st.length()); //returns 5
System.out.println(checking.length());  //returns 11
System.out.println(checking); //it prints <now> correctly
```

The string in input is like: `<now> 236 62 elena information-relation`

Comment: Please respect naming conventions.

Comment: Please format your post. This wall of text is hardly readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved re-saving the text file using UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 7):

Strings are [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) :

> [Note:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) The String class is immutable, so that once it is created a
>   String object cannot be changed. The String class has a number of
>   methods, some of which will be discussed below, that appear to modify
>   strings. Since strings are immutable, what these methods really do is
>   **create and return a new string that contains the result of the
>   operation**.

So it should be :

```
Checking = Checking.replace(" ","");
Checking = Checking.replace("/t","");
```

Or even better ([method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)) :

```
Checking = Checking.replace(" ","").replace("/t","");
```

Also please respect [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable so you need to assign.

```
Checking = Checking.replace(" ","");
Checking = Checking.replace("/t","");
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it shorter you can also do this:

```
String Checking = W[0].replace(" ", "").replace("/t", "");
```

Of course this depends on your preferences.